# Tableau: filter value N/A in the URL not working

Tags: tableau-api, urlencode

One of my filters has value "N/A" and I want to pass it in the URL when a dashboard is opened. We are also using JS API to embed dashboards and our Tableau Server Version is 2019.3.1

I have tried many things but the filter does not load with N/A applied. I have checked the tableau kb article https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/special-characters-in-url-parameters  and tried but it does not work.

**Passing N/A in the url**

```
%26Operator%3DWolverine%26State%3DUtah%26First%5c%20Production%5c%20Year%3DN%5C%2FA  
&Operator=Wolverine&State=Utah&First%5c%20Production%5c%20Year=N%5C%2FA  
&Operator=Wolverine&State=Utah&First+Production+Year=N%5C%2FA  
&Operator=Wolverine&State=Utah&First+Production+Year=N%2FA
```

I have also tried to pass the value in JS like below

```
tableauViz = new tableau.Viz(frameDiv[0], url, {  
        highdpi: true,  
        hideTabs: true,  
        hideToolbar: true,  
        "Operator": "Wolverine",  
        "First Production Year": "N/A",  
      });
```

But none of the above work, has anyone encountered such issue? Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain however you attempt to pass N/A, that / is going to be interpreted as a locator. I would suggest you add in some logic in the JS to interpret N-A, or NA, or Z35 as your N/A. Either that or add a calculated field and a case statement to convert your N/A to a number.

An excerpt from the link you included in your question, states / is a reserved character.

---

Network Working Group: Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax - 2.2.

Reserved Characters.

According to the above resource, the following characters are "reserved" (likely to cause errors in URLS unless encoded):  ! * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ? # [ ]

Comment: hi @Stryder, many thanks for the reply. I checked the documentation and it says to escape the reserved characters with a encoding value of a \ and character itself. which i already tried. But really confused as to why its not working :(

Comment: can you please elaborate the first part of the answer about adding some logic in JS, i did understand it.

Comment: In your question above you are passing in N/A in the JS, pass in something else. Use an alias or a calculated field to convert N/A in your data to the value you pass in JS.